# Appropriate status code for a invalid form

Tags: forms, http, http-status-codes

The data could not have been inputted by a typical user due to client-side validation. Is "400 Bad Request" the appropriate status code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain the form is invalid `400 Bad Request` is acceptable. However depending on why you believe a form is invalid you may also choose to use 
`status code 422 Unprocessable Entity.`
 This status code is designed to handle the use case where an submitted request is understood by the server and the request is syntactically correct, but the server was unable to process the instructions contained within the request.

Another possibly appropriate error code would be `415 Unsupported Media Type.` This error code should be used when the server fails to understand the request due to an invalid type of form. For example, if a server expected a JSON value but was given XML it should in theory return a `415 Unsupported Media Type` code.